# Overloading I/O operator C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the << operator. I'm expecting the output to be InitializingHello WorldOut but it is just outputting Hello World. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Thanks for your help.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;


  ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const char* &s)
  {
    out << "Initializing" << s << "Out";
    return out;
  }

  void main() {

    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    system("Pause");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is an overload for << with the exact same prototype. The compiler cannot decide which to use...

Comment: The prototypes are not the same, the standard one is not a reference. And even it they where the same, he wouldn't get a linker error because they are in different namespaces; he'd get an ambiguous call instead.

Comment: If the compiler couldn't decide, he'd get a compiler error. The compiler just doesn't pick one at random...

Answer (score 3):

`"Hello World"` is actually of type `const char[12]`, which can decay into an r-value (temporary) of type `const char *`, but your function takes a **reference** to a `const char*`, and as you may know, you cannot bind a reference to a non-const r-value. So your operator is not called, but instead the standard `ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const char* s)` is.

PS. Please do not write `void main()`. It should be `int main()` unless you are in an embedded system (not likely).

Comment: Even in an embedded system, `void main()` is not a valid C++ signature for main.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a `operator<<` for `const char*` defined in the standard library, which is used in the output. Your overload is not used because the temporary string literal cannot be bound to the non-`const` reference in the operators second parameter.

If you remove the reference or make it const, then your operator *is* called. It doesn't even conflict with the one in your standard library, since that one is implemented as a function template. Yours is not, and non-templated functions are preferred by the compiler.

If it is then called, it leads to a stack overflow because `out << "Initializing"` immediately calls the same operator again recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I think that since the left hand side is in the `std` namespace, it's using the function `ostream& std::operator << (ostream &out, const char* s)` that's defined in the `std` namespace instead of yours in the global namespace.  If you were to try to put yours into the `std` namespace, you'd get a linker error.  Your only real hope is to change the types of one side or the other, probably by making a wrapper around them.

```
struct charptr {
    const char* ptr;
    charptr(const char* p) :ptr(p) {}
};
ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const charptr &s)
{
    out << "Initializing" << s.ptr << "Out";
    return out;
}
int main() {  //int main, not void
    cout << charptr("Hello World") << endl;
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: You have to make that `charptr &` parameter `const`.

Comment: I don't think there is a `std::operator << (ostream &out, const char* &s)`. There is however a `std::operator << (ostream &out, const char* s)`. Notice the reference in the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

rodrigo pointed out that the type of a string literal is `const char[x]`, and I had an evil idea:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int len>
ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const char (&s)[len])
  {
    out << ((const char*)"Initializing") << ((const char*)s) << ((const char*)"Out");
    return out;
  }

  int main() { 
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  }
```

http://ideone.com/7wCNy